# How to remove from list if only given partial match

Tags: list, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a situation where I want to remove items from a list.  I only have part of the list item, so the typical remove from list isn't working for me since it's not a complete match.

I want to delete all instances of the match, and not just the first match.

I know exactly how many indexes are in the list item; however my search will only contain 3 of the 6 index items.

I'm using Python 3.6

Name of list is DV

This is what I'm trying so far:

```
c = Brian,Eats,Dinner
if c in DV:
     DV.remove(str(Brian,Eats,Dinner))
```

Sample of the list:

```
OrderedDict([('Category', 'Random'), ('Date Added', '03-03-2017'), ('Location', ''), ('Name', 'Brian'), ('Activity', 'Eats'), ('Meal', 'Dinner')])
OrderedDict([('Category', 'Random'), ('Date Added', '03-03-2017'), ('Location', ''), ('Name', 'Joe'), ('Activity', 'Runs'), ('Meal', 'Breakfast')])
OrderedDict([('Category', 'Random'), ('Date Added', '03-03-2017'), ('Location', ''), ('Name', 'Brian'), ('Activity', 'Eats'), ('Meal', 'Dinner')])
OrderedDict([('Category', 'Random'), ('Date Added', '03-03-2017'), ('Location', ''), ('Name', 'Brian'), ('Activity', 'Eats'), ('Meal', 'Dinner')])
```

This doesn't work, because I don't have the complete part, I think.

If I try it with the complete value, it removes it from the list.  The problem is that I only know for a fact the value of 3 of the items.  The other 3 are irrelevant.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you provide an example of a) how you would specify what you want removed and b) which items from your sample list should be removed?  "This doesn't work" doesn't help much.

Comment: In the code above, I'm listing what I want to remove and how I'm trying to remove it.  Please let me know if I can provide anything else.

Comment: Suppose an item in DV had ('Location','Brian'), ('Activity', 'Eats'), ('Meal', 'Dinner'); should that get removed?

Comment: No, Scott.  It should only get removed if it is in the specific index.  With my example, it doesn't matter what the values are for indexes 0 through 2.  It only matters if my match is in indexes 3 through 5.

Comment: So you have a list of `OrderedDict`s and want to remove the dict if all of the specified values are in the dict?

Comment: Yes, exactly.  I may only have some of the values and not all of them like my example.  I may not always know the values for some.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new list containing only those that don't match all of the specified values.

```
from collections import OrderedDict


data = [
    OrderedDict([('Category', 'Random'), ('Date Added', '03-03-2017'), ('Location', ''),
                 ('Name', 'Brian'), ('Activity', 'Eats'), ('Meal', 'Dinner')]),
    OrderedDict([('Category', 'Random'), ('Date Added', '03-03-2017'), ('Location', ''),
                 ('Name', 'Joe'), ('Activity', 'Runs'), ('Meal', 'Breakfast')]),
    OrderedDict([('Category', 'Random'), ('Date Added', '03-03-2017'), ('Location', ''),
                 ('Name', 'Brian'), ('Activity', 'Eats'), ('Meal', 'Dinner')]),
    OrderedDict([('Category', 'Random'), ('Date Added', '03-03-2017'), ('Location', ''),
                 ('Name', 'Brian'), ('Activity', 'Eats'), ('Meal', 'Dinner')])
]

# tuple of key, value pairs to check
key_values = ('Name', 'Brian'), ('Activity', 'Eats'), ('Meal', 'Dinner')
res = [d for d in data if not all(d.get(k) == v for k, v in key_values)]
```

---

If you want to have multiple groups of checks then you can do.

```
key_values_lst = [
    (('Name', 'Brian'), ('Activity', 'Eats'), ('Meal', 'Dinner')),
    (('Name', 'Joe'), ('Activity', 'Eats'), ('Meal', 'Breakfast'))
]

res = [d for d in data if not any(all(d.get(k) == v for k, v in key_values)
                                  for key_values in key_values_lst)]
```

You can also trim down the list using the following instead if you will always use the same keys and want to reduce typing if you have lots of groups.

```
keys = 'Name', 'Activity', 'Meal'
key_values_lst = [
    list(zip(keys, ('Brian', 'Eats', 'Dinner'))),
    list(zip(keys, ('Joe', 'Eats', 'Breakfast')))
]
```

---

Output

```
[OrderedDict([('Category', 'Random'),
              ('Date Added', '03-03-2017'),
              ('Location', ''),
              ('Name', 'Joe'),
              ('Activity', 'Runs'),
              ('Meal', 'Breakfast')])]
```